# Including font assets in Allegro fails with "al_draw_ustr: Assertion `font' failed" when using a "absolute" path that resolves against a assets folder

Tags: c++, cmake, allegro

I am trying to make a little game for practice in `C++`. I am using the `Clion` IDEA which uses `CMake` for it's build system.

So I have this project set up which uses the `Allegro` game library and I can get it working fine for now with me CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(my-game)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

# Set executeable
add_executable(game ${SOURCE_FILES})

#Include Allegro
include_directories(/usr/include/allegro5/)
link_directories(/usr/include/allegro5/)

#connect all the libraries you need
set(game_LIBS
        liballegro.so
        liballegro_dialog.so
        liballegro_image.so
        liballegro_font.so
        liballegro_ttf.so
)
target_link_libraries(game ${game_LIBS})
```

Now the problem is that in my project root folder I have this folder called `assets` and inside of it I would like to store my assets. For now there is a `fonts` folder in there which contains a `arial.ttf` file which I would like to use to display some text in my game.

Now the line I would use to get this asset and use it in my application should be something similar:

```
ALLEGRO_FONT *font24 = al_load_ttf_font("/assets/fonts/arial.ttf", 24, 0);
```

But for some reason when I launch the application and I start to use that `font24` pointer, I get this error:

```
game: /build/buildd/allegro5-5.0.10/addons/font/text.c:77: al_draw_ustr: Assertion `font' failed.
```

Now if I use this line instead:

```
ALLEGRO_FONT *font24 = al_load_ttf_font("/home/kaspar/Documents/Coding-projects/ClionProjects/my-game/assets/fonts/arial.ttf", 24, 0);
```

Then the application will be able to print the text with the desired font just fine.

So what must I do so that I would be able to reference my assets in the project more easily? I imagine that pointing to a file with it's full system path is not really a healthy practice..

Comment: On an unrelated note, if you plan to distribute this, consider the copyright of the font. Many fonts cannot be distributed due to copyright.

Comment: It will be used just for learning :) But thanks for the warning!

Comment: Forward slash represents the [root directory](http://www.linfo.org/root_directory.html). `/assets` is likely looking for assets in the root of your computer. You will need to use relative paths and make sure the assets are copied with the bundle.

Comment: How would I go about copying the assets into my bundle?

Comment: Just assume that they are present in your application's working directory : `ALLEGRO_FONT *font24 = al_load_ttf_font("assets/fonts/arial.ttf", 24, 0);`, e.g. without the first `/`. If this file doesn't exist, it means that the installation is somehow incomplete and you can't continue with loading the program.

Comment: Okay, If I moved the application into my root project folder then it worked fine now. But when I compile to program, all my output is created into a seperate folder called Debug. Is there a way to have CMake copy the assets there when making the compilation?

Comment: Check out this repo, you can use this as a reference https://github.com/SasLuca/raylib-cmake-template